# Shrink window film problems

Tags: winterizing

We installed Climaloc window film according to the directions on package. It shrunk well and we were pleased. The next day there were lots of wrinkles so again used the hair dryer and the windows looked great. Same thing has happened two more times. So we have gone over them 4 times. Each time I was concerned about overshrinking so we made sure we stopped when all the wrinkles were gone. The film felt taunt. Now I notice that one of the films has two holes in it, about the size of a dime. About 5 inches of another one has pulled away from the tape on one side. the wrinkles were all out of it about an hour ago but they are coming back. Has anyone had the same experience? Is there a way of repairing these?
The room where these windows are is an unheated sunroom. Does this make a difference in the ability of the shrinkwrap being able to stay shrunk?
Thanks for any help you can offer.
D.F.

Comment: I have extensive experience with both 3M and Frost King films. Neither relaxed after being shrunk. You have a defective (or inferior) product, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone had the same experience?

No, I haven't seen that happen with 3M or FrostKing.

> Is there a way of repairing these?

I have accidentally melted the film/trimmed wrong/had kids poke holes in it. I have successfully patched 4" holes that have lasted a season using [indoor weather sealing tape](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000CBIFF).

Comment: Your garden variety clear packaging tape works very well for small patches and penetration reinforcement (blind strings, for example). It doesn't shrink, but it doesn't really need to.